# Make Python built-in stream wrappers not close underlying BytesIO

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am creating in-memory files as `io.BytesIO` objects.

The file content is created using various built-in Python wrappers on top, such as `io.TextIOWrapper` or `csv.DictWriter` (just an example, I'm using more of Python's stdlib):

```py
def generate_file():
    raw_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    with io.TextIOWrapper(raw_bytes, encoding='utf-8') as wrapper:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wrapper, ["a", "b", "c"])
        writer.writeheader()
    return raw_bytes
```

This approach fails, because `TextIOWrapper` will close its underlying stream = our `raw_bytes`:

```py
generate_file().seek(0)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

According to https://bugs.python.org/issue21363 , the buffer can be detached, but that doesn't help either, because then the context manager raises another error:

```py
def generate_file():
    raw_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    with io.TextIOWrapper(raw_bytes, encoding='utf-8') as wrapper:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wrapper, ["a", "b", "c"])
        writer.writeheader()
        wrapper.detach()
    return raw_bytes

generate_file().seek(0)

ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached
```

I found two solutions:

1. Partial hack: don't use context managers, then the method above works (context manager won't try to access the detached object).
2. General hack: make BytesIO ignore any `close()` calls:

```py
class NonClosingBytesIO(io.BytesIO):

    def close(self):
        pass


def generate_file():
    raw_bytes = NonClosingBytesIO()
    with io.TextIOWrapper(raw_bytes, encoding='utf-8') as wrapper:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(wrapper, ["a", "b", "c"])
        writer.writeheader()
    return raw_bytes

generate_file().getvalue()

b'a,b,c\r\n'
```

**Question:** Is that safe? Can you come up with a better (cleaner) solution?

Comment: The only thing I could come up with was, as you said, to not use a context manager, write the data to the `TextIOWrapper`, force a flush of the buffer, store the contents of `raw_bytes.getvalue()` in a separate object, manually close the buffer, then return the separate bytes object. I don't think it's particularly pretty, but it doesn't seem to break anything. As for if subclassing and destroying the `close` method is safe, I have no idea.

Comment: I think it could be safer. I defined also custom destructor: `def __del__(self): BytesIO.close(self)` and call it explicitly when i want the memory to be free'ed